# Create a blog that only I can post - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, blogs

This question may be stupid but I want to create a blog with rails so only I as an Admin can post Articles and others can comment to articles but they don't need to create an account to comment.

So basically how to make it so only I have an User/Account and with that user I can post Articles when I Log In.
I thought of matching the login action to a "secret" route for example like /blablalogin.

Comment: I can suggest you a best engine of rails https://github.com/radar/forem

Comment: use Active Admin so that from active admin part you are able to create articles.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate controller for blog and also create a user access level. Now you can add your user to a special role who can manage Blog controller.

To create access level you can use devise with cancan.

> [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
>
> [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

**Update:**

Also you can add this with active admin as Gaurav Gupta said.

Comment: Thank you, and about the Log In view, I will be the only Account in the blog so only I can post articles and that's it, but does it matter if others see the Login page?

Comment: You can change the login screen url to your custom name. And also make sure that google and other search engine don't index the login page.

Answer (score 0):

I would do...

- Create a `Post` model running `rails g model post title:string body:text`

  ```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :admin_user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  end
  ```
- Install [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/tree/master/docs#activeadmin-documentation) for admin site. Easily you can create a blog posts CRUD using Active Admin.
- Create `User` model. Using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) you can solve the "login part" for users.

  > You don't need devise if it`s not necessary to be logged in to write comments
- Create `Comment` model. `rails g model post title:string body:text user:references post:references`

  ```
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user # you won't need this relation if users don't need to be logged in.
    belongs_to :post
  end
  ```
- Create a `PostsController` with `index` and `show` actions only.
- Create a `CommentsController` with `create` action only.
  Don't forget permitted params:

  ```
  def permitted_params
    params.require(:post).permit(comments_attributes: [:title, :body])
  end
  ```
- The routes:

  ```
  resources :posts, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:create]  
  end
  ```

  You will have:

  - `GET /posts` the view containing posts list
  - `GET /posts/:id` view for specific post. Here you need a form to enter comments pointing to `POST /posts/:id/comments`
  - `POST /posts/:id/comments` endpoint to save comments for a single post.
- You should know about [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) it you want to create comments for a single post in a rails way.